# How to debug a program with an infinite loop?

Tags: java, debugging

I'm trying to debug my program. To see where it goes wrong, I need to look at the output. However because it uses recursion indefinitely, the only way to stop the program is to recompile which wipes the output. How should I debug?

I'm calling DTNode.

Here's my class:

```
package DecisionTree;

public class DTNode {

    Instance[] instances;
    double cutoff;
    DTNode left, right;

    public DTNode (Instance[] instance, int l, int r) {
      this.instances = instance;
      int i;
      int j = 0;
      int k = 0;
      int getIndex;
      double[] cutoff = new double[instance.length];
      double[] entropy = new double[instance.length];
      int[] split = new int[instance.length];
      double smallestEntropy;

      for(i=0; i<r; i++) {
        if(instance[i].label != instance[i+1].label) {
          cutoff[j] = (instance[i].attribute + instance[i+1].attribute)/2;
          split[j] = i;
          System.out.println("Cutoff is: " + cutoff[j] + ". Split is: " + split[j]);
          j++;
        }
      }

      for(k=0; k<j; k++) {
        entropy[k] = calcEntropy(instance, l, cutoff[k], r);
        System.out.println(entropy[k]);
      }

      smallestEntropy = entropy[0];
      getIndex = split[0];
      for(k=1; k<j; k++) {
        if (entropy[k] < smallestEntropy) {
          smallestEntropy = entropy[k];
          getIndex = k;
        }
      }
      System.out.println(getIndex + "   " + entropy[getIndex]);
      if((r - l) == 0 || j == 0) {
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
      }
      else{
        this.left = new DTNode(instance, l, getIndex);
        this.right = new DTNode(instance, getIndex+1, r);
      }
    }

    public double calcEntropy(Instance[] inst, int a, double b, int c) {
      int i;
      double leftSideCounter = 0;
      double rightSideCounter = 0;
      double leftTrue = 0;
      double rightTrue = 0;
      double leftSideEntropy = 0;
      double rightSideEntropy = 0;
      double leftTrueFraction;
      double leftFalseFraction;
      double rightTrueFraction;
      double rightFalseFraction;
      double leftTotalFraction;
      double rightTotalFraction;
      double entropy;

      for(i=a; i<=c; i++){
        if(inst[i].attribute < b) {
          leftSideCounter++;
        }
        else {
          rightSideCounter++;
        }
      }

      for(i=0; i<leftSideCounter; i++) {
        if(inst[i].label == true) {
          leftTrue++;
        }
      }

      for(i=(int)leftSideCounter; i<(int)(rightSideCounter+leftSideCounter); i++) {
        if(inst[i].label == true) {
          rightTrue++;
        }
      }


      leftTrueFraction = leftTrue/leftSideCounter;
      leftFalseFraction = (leftSideCounter-leftTrue)/leftSideCounter;

      rightTrueFraction = rightTrue/rightSideCounter;
      rightFalseFraction = (rightSideCounter-rightTrue)/rightSideCounter;

      leftTotalFraction = leftSideCounter/(leftSideCounter+rightSideCounter);
      rightTotalFraction = rightSideCounter/(leftSideCounter+rightSideCounter);

      if(leftTrue == 0 || (leftSideCounter - leftTrue) == 0) {
        leftSideEntropy = 0;
      }
      else{
      leftSideEntropy = -leftTrueFraction*logb2(leftTrueFraction)-leftFalseFraction*logb2(leftFalseFraction);
      }

      if (rightTrue == 0 || (rightSideCounter - rightTrue) == 0) {
        rightSideEntropy = 0;
      }
      else{
      rightSideEntropy = -rightTrueFraction*logb2(rightTrueFraction)-rightFalseFraction*logb2(rightFalseFraction);
      }
      entropy = leftSideEntropy*leftTotalFraction+rightSideEntropy*rightTotalFraction;

      System.out.println(leftTrue);
      System.out.println("leftTrueFraction = " + leftTrueFraction + ". leftFalseFraction = " + leftFalseFraction);
      System.out.println("rightTrueFraction = " + rightTrueFraction + ". rightFalseFraction = " + rightFalseFraction);
      System.out.println("leftTotalFraction = " + leftTotalFraction + ". rightTotalFraction = " + rightTotalFraction);
      System.out.println("leftSideEntropy = " + leftSideEntropy + ". rightSideEntropy = " + rightSideEntropy);
      return entropy;
    }

    public double logb2(double b) {
      return Math.log(b)/Math.log(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why a debugger wont' work...

Comment: With a debugger? With `System.out.println` statements put in to show you the state of variables? Basically, like you would debug anything else.

Comment: What's a debugger? I'm using DrJava

Comment: Well an example of what is wrong would be nice... what are you looping?

Comment: I can't see the System.out.println statements like I said in my OP because the program doesn't stop, and when I force it to stop, the printed statements disappear...

Comment: http://www.drjava.org/docs/user/ch09.html (from googling "DrJava debugger")

Comment: Can you show us the code that your trying to loop and is it possible to put the breakpoints outside of the loop?

Comment: I don't see a debugger menu anywhere in DrJava.. And I've shown the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All major IDE comes with debugging capability. You can easily debug the java file using those debugger.

1. Here is the tutorial for [Debugging with eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html).
2. How to debug in [intelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugging.html)
3. How to debug in [netbean](https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html)
4. Java native debugger [link here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html).

You can also find tons of video online. Just search Java debugging.